# Write and read from the same file- PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to write to a file and then read the data from the same file. But sometimes I am facing this issue that the file reading process is getting started even before the file writing gets finished. How can I solve this issue ? How can i make file writing process finish before moving ahead?

// writing to file

```
$string= <12 kb of specific data which i need>;
$filename.="/ttc/";
$filename.="datasave.html";
if($fp = fopen($filename, 'w')) 
{
    fwrite($fp, $string);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

//    writing to the file

```
$handle = fopen($filename, "r")  ;
$datatnc = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
$datatnc = addslashes($datatnc);
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: No code, no help. We're no fortunetellers.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Above is my code which i am using. for writing and reading

Comment: had to find answer by my own....:(..FLOCK is what i was looking for....http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_flock.asp

Comment: @RiteshKumar If you've found the answer to your question, please write an answer here.

Comment: I have pasted the code from the URL i mentioned as an answer. You may refer to that..:)

Answer (score 3):

The reason it does not work is because when you are done writing a string to the file the file pointer points to the end of the file so later when you try to read the same file with the same file pointer there is nothing more to read. All you have to do is rewind the pointer to the beginning of the file. Here is an example:

```
<?php
$fileName = 'test_file';
$savePath = "tmp/tests/" . $fileName;
//create file pointer handle
$fp = fopen($savePath, 'r+');
fwrite($fp, "Writing and Reading with same fopen handle!");
//Now rewind file pointer to start reading
rewind($fp);
//this will output "Writing and Reading with same fopen handle!"
echo fread($fp, filesize($savePath));
fclose($fp);
 ?>
```

Here is more info on the rewind() method http://php.net/manual/en/function.rewind.php

Answer (score 1):

I have mentioned the URL through which i got the solution. I implemented the same. If you want me to copy the text from that link then here it is :

```
$file = fopen("test.txt","w+");

    // exclusive lock

if (flock($file,LOCK_EX))
{
    fwrite($file,"Write something");
    // release lock
    flock($file,LOCK_UN);
}
else
{
    echo "Error locking file!";
}

fclose($file);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `fclose` after writing to close the file pointer and then `fopen` again to open it.